# How to filter data and execute command based on the output

Tags: bash, shell

I am using below shell script for getting certail data

test.sh

```
adb shell dumpsys battery | awk '/Battery current/{print}'
```

I get below output in terminal

```
Battery current : -286
```

How to check if Battery current value is > -1000 then execute an command "Command1"
else execute "Command 2"

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Just use `awk` to extract the field you want:

```
adb shell dumpsys battery | awk -F: '/Battery current/{print $2}'
```

If you want to put that value in a variable:

```
battery_current="$(adb shell dumpsys battery | awk -F: '/Battery current/{print $2}')"
```

And now you can use that in an `if` statement:

```
if [ "$battery_current" -gt -1000 ]; then
  ...do something...
else
  ...do something else...
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`, you can use the `system` function which executes cmd and returns its exit status

```
$ adb shell dumpsys battery | awk '/Battery current/ {current=$NF}{if (current > -1000) system("command.."); else system("comand..")}'
```

Answer (score 0):

The generic template would be like this :

```
jot 5 | {m,g}awk '{ system( (+$_)%3 ? "date" : "gdate +\47%s.%6N\47") }'

Fri Jun 17 09:19:18 EDT 2022
Fri Jun 17 09:19:18 EDT 2022
1655471958.225290
Fri Jun 17 09:19:18 EDT 2022
Fri Jun 17 09:19:18 EDT 2022
```

Your specific case would be like :

```
adb shell dumpsys battery | 

{m,g}awk '!_<NF { system(-1E3<+$NF ? _cmd1_ :_cmd_2_) }' FS='^ *Battery current[: ]+'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[[ "$(adb shell dumpsys battery|awk -F: '/Battery current/{print $2}')" -lt -1000 ]]  && 
commnad1 || 
command2
```